# Aggregate pandas dataframe but collapse duplicate cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['prefix_v1_0001',   'prefix_v1_0002',   'prefix_v1_0003',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0004',   'prefix_v1_0005'],
                   'knum': ['-',   '-',   'K03643',   'K02340',   'K02340',   'K02340',   'K02340',   'K02340',   'K03643',   '-'],
                   'definition': ['-',   '-',   'LPS-assembly lipoprotein',   'DNA polymerase III subunit delta [EC:2.7.7.7]',   'DNA polymerase III subunit delta [EC:2.7.7.7]',   'DNA polymerase III subunit delta [EC:2.7.7.7]',   'DNA polymerase III subunit delta [EC:2.7.7.7]',   'DNA polymerase III subunit delta [EC:2.7.7.7]',   'LPS-assembly lipoprotein',   '-'],
                   'A': ['-',   '-',   'Brite Hierarchies (09180)',   'Genetic Information Processing (09120)',   'Genetic Information Processing (09120)',   'Genetic Information Processing (09120)',   'Brite Hierarchies (09180)',   'Brite Hierarchies (09180)',   'Brite Hierarchies (09180)',   '-'],
                   'B': ['-',   '-',   'Protein families: signaling and cellular processes (09183)',   'Replication and repair (09124)',   'Replication and repair (09124)',   'Replication and repair (09124)',   'Protein families: genetic information processing (09182)',   'Protein families: genetic information processing (09182)',   'Protein families: signaling and cellular processes (09183)',   '-'],
                   'C': ['-',   '-',   'Transporters  (02000) [BR:ko0200]',   'DNA replication  (03030) [PATH:ko0303]',   'Mismatch repair  (03430) [PATH:ko0343]',   'Homologous recombination  (03440) [PATH:ko0344]',   'DNA replication proteins  (03032) [BR:ko0303]',   'DNA repair and recombination proteins  (03400) [BR:ko0340]',   'Transporters  (02000) [BR:ko0200]',   '-']})
```

And I want to group by `query`, and aggregate the other cells by using the '|' character.

This is my current code:

```
df.groupby('query').agg({'knum': lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()),
                         'definition': lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()),
                         'A': lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()),
                         'B': lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()),
                         'C': lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()),
                         })
```

However, because there are so many duplicate cell contents, my table looks like this:
[image]
But actually, for `query`: `prefix_v1_0004` there are actually only 2 unique values for `knum`.
I would like to get rid off all the duplicate values, or is there a way with `aggregate()`?

This is my desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I Understand Correctly:

try via `groupby()`+`agg()` and use `set` for unique values instead of `list`:

```
df=df.groupby('query').agg(lambda x:' | '.join(set(x)))
```

**OR**

If order is important then use `pd.unique()` for unique values:

```
df=df.groupby('query').agg(lambda x:' | '.join(pd.unique(x)))
```

**OR**

If want to perform on selected columns then create a list of those columns and perform aggregration only on those columns:

```
cols=['knum','definition','A','B','C']
df=df.groupby('query')[cols].agg(lambda x:' | '.join(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of list, use `set` which has unique values:

```
df.groupby('query').agg({'knum': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)),
                         'definition': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)),
                         'A': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)),
                         'B': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)),
                         'C': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)),
                         })
```